# JavaScript: How to properly loop through array and use values as keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am getting a JSON-string from a remote endpoint and want to use values as keys. So I am looping through the result like that:

```
(function() {
// Create the connector object
var myConnector = tableau.makeConnector();

var definitions = [];

// Define the schema
myConnector.getSchema = function(schemaCallback) {

$.ajax({
    url: apiUrl,
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    cache: false,
    headers: {
        'X-Auth-Token':'123',
        'X-Auth-User':'user1'
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response){

        $.each(response,function(key,value){

                console.log("inside loop");
                console.log(value);
                definitions[value.id]
                     = value.name;

        }); 

        console.log("inside ajax");
        console.log(definitions);
    }

});

console.log("done");
console.log(definitions);

// this is where I want to loop through my result
// whithout success (no console output
for (var key in definitions) {
        console.log(key);

    }

}; //     myConnector.getSchema = function(schemaCallback) {

})(); //function() {
```

This is the response from the API:

```
[
{
    "id": 123,
    "name": "Name1"
},
{
    "id": 456,
    "name": "Name2"
},
{
    "id": 789,
    "name": "Name3"
}]
```

This is the output of the first log command, inside the loop:

```
{id: 123, name: "Name1"}
id: 123
name: "Name1"
__proto__: Object
```

The problem is, the last log looks like this:

```
[123: "Name1", 456: "Name3", 789: "Name4"]
123: "Name1"
456: "Name2"
789: "Name3"
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)
```

The problem is clearly: The array length is shown as zero. And this I do not understand.

Later in this script I want to loop through this array again, but because of this strange result, I am not able to address the index keys.

What is it, that I am doing wrong?

### Additional information

I am working on a web connector for Tableau that will connect to an RESTful service's endpoint. Unfortunately I cannot publish the actual RESTful URL, because it provides private data.

I am using this simulator: http://tableau.github.io/webdataconnector/Simulator/

I added all the surroundings to the upper source code. There are few more lines of source code, but it's absolutely not related to my work (one more different loop and variable definitions).

I now tried the script in Firefox (Chrome before). The only result I get here is

```
done myConnector.js:97:5
[]
​
length: 0
​
<prototype>: Array []
```

All the other console.log's are not triggered.

Also Firefox complains about CORS, this is known because I already fixed the CORS-header server-side. **But nevertheless** at the end data is being received and populated to the simulator I am using (see URL above)!
Clearly I am misunderstanding something here...

Comment: Please add the full response value and formatted.

Comment: sure, thanks for the note

Comment: Although the code does not show it, this behaviour in the console happens when you log an array that at *that very moment* is still empty, but is populated asynchronously (e.g. with ajax). This is normal behaviour with the console.

Comment: @trincot you mean it takes some time for the array to show up as populated, even though the value is logged after population?

Comment: Please always add a working snippet of code, so it will be faster to help you.

Comment: In fact, your code does not show it, but I suspect you do the `console.log(definitions)` somewhere else. What takes time, is the ajax response. If you output `definitions` before the `success` callback has been called, then of course you get an empty array. But if you only *look* at the console *after* the `success` callback was called, then you will spot content in it. This is an (understandable) particularity of how the console works.

Comment: use `console.log(JSON.stringify(definitions))` to get the content at *that very moment*.

Comment: I'm not sure why `length` is showing as "0". But the array surely seems to contain data. What goes wrong when you try to loop through the array again?

Comment: @Staxaaaa Totall understand you, I added sourrouing lines, unfortunately that's all I can provide, hope thats enough.

Comment: @trincot actually that are all places where I use console.log. Interestingly, I am now trying it on firefox, where I only get one console-output, and thats the one marked with "done" - and there the array actually is empty, like, actually does not contain anything. Added this to the post. Will try the stringify-thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is on me and a misunderstanding of Ajax and asynchronious request. The comments on my question helped to see the problem.

As stated above, I am calling this script from another server (http://tableau.github.io/webdataconnector/Simulator/). The script itself sends a request to a third server.

Forcing the ajax-function to work synchroniously works:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: apiUrl,
        type: 'GET',
        crossDomain: true,
        cache: false,
        async: false,

        ...})
```

Now the console show the array as actually filled:

```
(790) [empty × 123, "Name1", empty × 123, "Name2", empty × 333, "Name3"]
123: "Name1"
456: "Name2"
789: "Name3"
length: 929
__proto__: Array(0)
```

So finally, it's not about referencing the array / object the wrong way, it's about the asynchronious call.

Answer (score 0):

You can try initializing definitions as an object instead of array ie. `var definitions = {}` and the ids its properties. So that you can easily loop through it with a for..in loop.

As the AJAX call is async the log might run on the empty array `definitions`.

```
for (id in definitions) {
// Logic
}
var len = Object.keys(definitions).length
```

Comment: This doesn't provide the length, though. That seems the be the OP's issue.

Comment: You can get the length using `Object.keys(definitions).length`

Comment: True, but that doesn't explain why the OP's array length is showing "0".

Comment: I would suggest to perform all the processing on the `definitions` in the for each callback. Note that the AJAX call is asynchronous.

Comment: I'm not sure I see what you mean. It is asynchronous, but the output is logged from within the `success` callback of the AJAX call and after the array is built; the AJAX is already finished at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Not work in IE. For crossbrowsers support use regular for loop.

```
for (var object of response) {
    console.log(object.id);
    console.log(object.name);
}
```

Regular for

```
var len = response.length;

for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
    var currentObject = response[i];

    console.log(currentObject.id);
    console.log(currentObject.name);
}
```

In this way you get properties and then can use they as key for looping over another array/object.

Comment: This doesn't provide the length, though. That seems the be the OP's issue.

Comment: if response equal to array per question. The length equal to 3.

Comment: Agreed, but the OP says it's showing up as "0" in the console.